# Why can't I select data from my LINQ sub query join?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am trying to get data from 2 tables using a left join to a nested query. This allows me to get data from Item table but not the cart(nested query) table:

```
 var q = from s in db.Items
                    join sub in (from c in db.Carts
                                 where c.CartID == 1
                                 group c by c.ItemID into g
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     ItemID = g.Key,
                                     Qty = g.Select(s => s.Qty)

                                 }) on s.ItemID equals sub.ItemID into a
                    select new ItemViewModel
                    {
                        CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
                        Description = s.Description,
                        Price = s.Price,

    **This being the issue------>>>>>>>** //Qty = a.Select(j => j.Qty),

                        ItemID = s.ItemID,
                        ItemName = s.ItemName
                    };


                    viewModel = q.ToList();
```

The query i am trying to acheive is:

```
select Items.*, Cart.Qty
from Items
left join (select ItemID, Qty from carts where CartID = 1 ) Cart 
on Items.ItemID = Cart.ItemID
```

Comment: One important thing is, what is the type of `ItemViewModel.Qty` property?

Comment: Property is set as an int, but the error given is cannot convert system.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<int> to int.

Comment: `Select` always returns a collection. If you want to fold it into a single value, you need to use appropriate folding functions: `Count`, `Sum`, `Aggregate` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupJoin` with `SelectMany` for `LEFT JOIN` SQL Query and get the desired output.

```
    var result = db.Items.GroupJoin(db.Carts.Where(x => x.CartID == 1), item => item.ItemID, cart => cart.ItemID, 
                 (item, cart) => new { item, cart })
                .SelectMany(x => x.cart.DefaultIfEmpty(), (it, ca) =>
                {
                    return new ItemViewModel
                {
                        ItemName = it.item.ItemName,
                        Price = it.item.Price,
                        ItemID = it.item.ItemID,
                        // ... .... .... 
                        // Fill the required columns from it.Item property..
                        Qty = ca != null ? ca.Qty : 0
                    };
                }).ToList();
```

EDIT: The `LINQ` version with `SelectMany`.

```
var result = from s in db.Items
        join sub in (from c in db.Carts
                     where c.CartID == 1
                     select c)
        on s.ItemID equals sub.ItemID into joined
        from row in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new ItemViewModel 
        { 
            CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
            Description = s.Description,
            Price = s.Price,
            Qty = row != null ? row.Qty : 0,
            ItemID = s.ItemID,
            ItemName = s.ItemName
        };
```

The [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lEIG27) with sample data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OP asked for an inner join solution, and this here represents a left outer join, I think.

Comment: Correct it is `LEFT JOIN` but check the SQL in OP. It is clearly mentioned as `LEFT JOIN`. He need items but if Qty presents in Cart, that too. Not `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, and assuming that `ItemViewModel.Qty` property is just an `int`, the simplest form of the query you want is:

```
var q = from item in items
        join cart in
          (from cart in carts where cart.CartID == 1 select cart)
          on item.ItemID equals cart.ItemID into itemCarts
        select new ItemViewModel
        {
            ItemID = item.ItemID,
            Qty = itemCarts.Sum(cart => cart.Qty)
        };
```

If you want to only slightly modify/fix *your* query:

```
var q = from s in db.Items
        join sub in (from c in db.Carts
                     where c.CartID == 1
                     group c by c.ItemID into g
                     select new
                     {
                         ItemID = g.Key,
                         Qty = g.Sum(s => s.Qty)
                         // or Qty = g.Select(s => s.Qty)
                         // and below: Qty = a.SelectMany(x => x.Qty).Sum()
                     })
            on s.ItemID equals sub.ItemID into a
        select new ItemViewModel
        {
            CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
            Description = s.Description,
            Price = s.Price,
            Qty = a.Sum(x => x.Qty),
            ItemID = s.ItemID,
            ItemName = s.ItemName
        };
```